# How to replicate Google photos scrolling thumb for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to replicate the google photos scrolling behavior in our app and failing miserably.

Desired outcome:

[image]

I have a simple recyclerview where right now I'm using the fastscroller line and thumb.
The problem with that it redefines the height of the thumb drawable based on the content size.

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/pages"
            app:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            app:fastScrollHorizontalThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
            app:fastScrollHorizontalTrackDrawable="@drawable/line_drawable"
            app:fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
            app:fastScrollVerticalTrackDrawable="@drawable/line_drawable">
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by defining height and width for thumb

here is how I have done it

[ic_scroll.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz4Z5.png)

**thumb.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_scroll" android:width="44dp" android:height="40dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

**thumb_drawable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb" android:state_pressed="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy and customizable option

Create an ic_asset_1.xml drawable /* This is a Vector */

Customize the background and arrows color according to your needs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="22.94dp"
android:height="38.3dp"
android:viewportWidth="22.94"
android:viewportHeight="38.3">
<path
  android:pathData="M22.94,37.2a15.65,15.65 0,0 1,-5.76 1.1C7.69,38.3 
  0,29.72 0,19.15S7.69,0 17.18,0a15.56,15.56 0,0 1,5.54 1"
  android:fillColor="#4298f5"/>
<path android:pathData="M8.02,21.06l7.31,0l-3.65,5.45l-3.66,-5.45z"
  android:fillColor="#fff"
 />
 <path
  android:pathData="M15.23,16.02l-7.11,0l3.56,-5.55l3.55,5.55z"
  android:fillColor="#fff"
 />
 </vector>
```

Create an scrollbar_thumb.xml drawable

Customize height and width according to your needs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_asset_1" 
android:width="30dp" 
android:height="40dp"
/>
</layer-list>
```

Create a new style in styles.xml

```
 <style name="scrollbar_style">
    <item name="android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack">true</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarStyle">outsideOverlay</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:fadeScrollbars">true</item>
    <item 
     name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@drawable/scrollbar_thumb</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarFadeDuration">800</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade">500</item>
</style>
```

Add this style in recyler view like this

```
   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        style="@style/scrollbar_style"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        />
```